# Python's equivalent of get (,'color') function in Matlab

Tags: python, plot

I am a newbie in Python.  Please excuse my dummy question.  I want to implement something very similar to the following Matlab code, but am stuck with its Python equivalents:

```
...
Subplot (2,1,1);
H = plot (rand(100,5));
C = get (H, 'Color')
H = area (myX, myY);
H(1).FaceColor = C1;
H(2).FaceColor = C2;
Grid on;
...
```

Could someone kindly shed me some lights?  Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what that code does in Matlab, we're gonna have a hard time telling you what the Python equivalent is.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply, and sorry about my assumption that everyone knows matlab.  Matlab code above first created a plot of 5 random data series. Then it applied real data to the plot area, using the color properties from the first two random series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at matplotlib for plotting. Then, you can use `get_color()` for line objects.

this is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=np.random.random((100,5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lines=ax.plot(a)

#line_colors is a list of colors used for the lines in this plot. they are in string format, i.e. 'b' for blue etc.
line_colors=[l.get_color() for l in lines]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your tips, jlarsch, appreciated.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd love to accept but I don't see the Accept button anywhere (again, please execute my dumbness here).  BTW, could you also tell me the python version of matlab area() function, as in h=area(xx,yy), please?  Thanks again, jlarsch!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow